# Which is faster? Iteration or DQL?

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, dql

Which of these is faster?

Given that I have already done the following...

```
$query = $em->createQuery("SELECT g FROM SSMURBS\Group g WHERE g.id = {$_POST['group_id']}");
$group = $query->getSingleResult();
```

Which of the following lines of code is best?

(1)

```
$query = $em->createQuery("SELECT partial p.{id} FROM SSMURBS\Person p WHERE :groupId MEMBER OF p.groups");
$query->setParameter('groupId', $_POST['group_id']);
$member_ids_result = $query->getScalarResult();
$member_ids = $member_ids_result[0];
```

or...

(2)

```
$group_member_ids = array();
foreach( $group->members as $member ){
    $group_member_ids[] = $member->id;
}
```

Comment: Although Doctrine escapes vars, it's generally a good idea to validate user input ($_POST['group_id']) before using in a query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both methods seem to do two different things.

- The first gets all and populates $member_ids with the first result.
- The second iterates through each member in the group

The best way to iterate through results is to use the query's `iterate()` method. [See docs ->](http://www.doctrine-project.org/docs/orm/2.0/en/reference/batch-processing.html#iterating-results)

```
$query = $em->createQuery("SELECT g FROM SSMURBS\Group g WHERE g.id = ?1");
$query->setParameter(1, $_POST['group_id']);

$group_member_ids = array();
$iterableResult = $query->iterate();

foreach ($iterableResult as $member) {
    $group_member_ids[] = $member->id;
}
```

Like I said in my comment on your question, validate user input before using in the query. Just to be safe.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I did validate the POST variables before in code I didn't include in my question. But what is the best way to do that? between `empty()`,`isset()`, and `is_null()`? I know `empty()` will only work to validate non-zero values, but I find that sometimes the value is null, sometimes it's not set, sometimes it's an empty string....what's the best way?

Comment: In this case I assume `group_id` is an integer, so you would do something like `if (isset($_POST['group_id']) && is_numeric($_POST['group_id']))`. So strings you may need to use `htmlentities()` or `htmlspecialchars()` clean up the data. It really depends on the value you expect.